# How to monitor traffic and bandwidth usage in complex network?

Tags: networking

i work in a medium size company. 
We have 100 clients and 4-5 network switch. 
I would like to monitor bandwidth usage (peak, volumes) overall, not from my single pc.
How to do ? 
Thanks

Comment: This question, which shows a total lack of effort on your part, doesn't really deserve an answer. Nevertheless, try Googling for things like nagios, mrtg and "network monitoring".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at tools like Cacti which can request those performance metrics via snmp from your switches. We monitor our switches this way. Depending on the manufacturer of your switches there may be even more ways to solve your problem. Maybe your switches are capable to export NetFlow data?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetFlow